# Can't get specific data from table, others work

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT sid FROM staff WHERE position > 0 ORDER BY name ASC";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
    $staff->getInfo($row['sid']);
    echo "<a href='index.php?page=staff&sid=".$staff->sid."'>";
    echo $staff->name;
    echo "</a>, ";
    echo $staff->printPosition();
    echo "<br />";
  endwhile;
```

I can display the staff name and position, but when I try to grab the sid for the url - it doesn't work. It just ends up as:

index.php?page=staff&sid=

Any way to solve this?

EDIT:

```
function getInfo($sid)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE sID = '$sid'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $this->sid = $row['sid'];
        $this->branch = $row['branch'];     
        $this->name = $row['name'];
        $this->position = $row['position']; 
        $this->startDate = $row['startDate'];
        $this->div = $row['div'];
        $this->tag = $row['tag'];
    }
```

Comment: What does `$staff->getInfo()` do?

Comment: explain more and give us a better view from you problem so maybe we can be a help. what really does `$staff->getInfo()` do?

Comment: please update your question with the code, not in the comments

Comment: just edit you main question and add these data too it so it becom a little readable...

Comment: Updated original question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic debugging dictates you should be putting var_dump in the getInfo function at the point of assignment to 'row'. If the vardump shows that row[sid] is empty then there's a problem with your query. My guess is that the column name is sID, when you do query 1 you technically alias the column to all lowercase sid. But when you do select *, the mysql_fetch assigns the actual column names including case to the variable. So check the case of your columns in the db and make sure your array keys match the case.

Comment: You should indicate what the problem was so that others who search for an issue like yours will mow what to look for.